# How does JS calculate the delta in wheel events?

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, pixel

On a single mouse scroll the [delta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY) varies from screen to screen which is expected.

The [DeltaMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaMode) is 0 which means the delta in the event is in pixels.

Problem is that on different screens the delta given by these events are not proportionate.

On a screen 1080px height, I get a deltaY of 4 on a single mouse scroll.
and on a screen of 1600px height, I get a deltaY of 8 on a single mouse scroll.

The Scroll is not proportionate to the user screen and not affected by the current window height/width.

Comment: _"On a screen 1080px height, I get a deltaY of 4 on a single mouse scroll. and on a screen of 1600px height, I get a deltaY of 8 on a single mouse scroll."_ - so maybe that just _is_ how far that "single scroll" moved the page content in each case?

Comment: Shouldn't it be proportionate.
If it was just based on screen size then the below values should be equal right?

1) `4/1080 = 0.0037`

2) `8/1600 = 0.005`

Comment: The actual calculation will vary based on your OS settings, your mouse settings, and possibly also your browser's settings. Mix all these up, add some fancy "smoothing" here and there, take some inertia maybe, and ... we can't answer. But (as a macOS user) I don't see why it would be relative to the screen size.